# Does requireProperty not require a typical maven property in maven enforcer?

Tags: maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am trying to require that a particular property is defined during the build using the maven enforcer plugin and the `RequireProperty` rule.

The relevant part of my `pom.xml` is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <properties>
        <foo>bar</foo>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>require-properties</id>
                        <goals><goal>enforce</goal></goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireProperty>
                                    <property>${foo}</property>
                                    <message>foo must be defined -${foo}-</message>
                                </requireProperty>
                            </rules>
                            <!-- Disabling, since it seems to not notice properties that are defined -->
                            <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run this, the enforcer rule fails.

```
$ mvn install 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------------< test:test >------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (require-properties) @ test ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
foo must be defined -bar-
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.398 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-15T11:45:58-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It also fails if I define it on the command line.

```
$ mvn install -Dfoo=quz
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------------< test:test >------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M1:enforce (require-properties) @ test ---
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireProperty failed with message:
foo must be defined -quz-
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is this rule not for `<properties>` values?  From the message, it is clear that the value is actually set.

I also tried adding `<regex>.*</regex>` with no effect.

How to I check that a maven property is set?

**Real case details**

In the example, the property is defined in the pom, so it sort of redundant to include the check.  In the real case, the plugin is defined in the parent pom and the property is defined in the leaf pom.  The behavior is the same in the real case.

**mvn -version**

Apache Maven 3.6.0 (97c98ec64a1fdfee7767ce5ffb20918da4f719f3; 2018-10-24T14:41:47-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.14.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Comment: Please try `<property>foo</property>`  instead of `<property>${foo}</property>`

Comment: Agree with @khmarbaise and check requiredProperty https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html

Comment: @khmarbaise is right.  I was so used to wrapping property names in `${...}` that I just did that automatically here.  And it looked so normal that I couldn't see it as a problem.